# Is there a way to run xpra on tor network

Tags: linux, ssh, xorg, tor, xpra

I can ssh into tor url with torsocks but it does not work on xpra

command I used

```
$ torsocks xpra attach ssh://user@torlink.onion/100
```

I got this error :

WARNING torsocks[27516]: [syscall] Unsupported syscall number 39. Denying the call (in tsocks_syscall() at syscall.c:604)

My port 22 is open for tor connections on /etc/tor/torrc

Answer (score 0):

If you can ssh to that host then for sure you can use xpra.
I have no idea what this syscall 39 is, but if this is somehow caused by the paramiko ssh backend, try the plain ssh backend: `xpra --ssh="ssh -v" ...`

Comment: I still got syscall 39 error

Comment: Then you must be getting that error with plain ssh connections too.
Either ssh works or it doesn't.

Comment: ssh and ssh with x forwarding works but xpra does not.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, xpra just runs `ssh -v ..`
My guess is that something else is wrong with your installation.